# SQL Azure - Failed Connections - But no problems?

Tags: sql-server, entity-framework, azure, azure-sql-database

We recently migrated a client to the SQL Azure platform during the course of a production deployment.  By all outward signs, it was successful:  the web apps connected to it are all working.

However, when we look at the Azure monitor, we see many failed connections.  We haven't been able to find much documentation explaining what constitutes a failed connection.  And none of our users have been reporting problems.  Does anyone know how this could be?

[image]

Using the sample query from this article ([View Connection Issues on an SQL Azure Instance](http://www.clickrex.com/post/42345168417/view-connection-issues-on-an-sql-azure-instance))

```
SELECT      
            [Date From] = EL.[start_time],
            [Date To] = EL.[end_time],
            [Database Name] = EL.[database_name],
            [Event Type] = EL.[event_type],
            [Event Sub Type] = EL.[event_subtype_desc],
            [Description] = EL.[description],
            [Additional Data] = EL.additional_data
FROM sys.event_log EL
WHERE EL.event_type != 'connection_successful'
AND EL.event_subtype_desc != 'idle_connection_timeout'
ORDER BY [Date From] DESC
```

We see results like this:

```
2013-04-19 16:40:00.0000000 2013-04-19 16:45:00.0000000 [DATABASE]  connection_failed   blocked_by_firewall Client IP address is not allowed to access the server.  NULL
2013-04-19 16:40:00.0000000 2013-04-19 16:45:00.0000000             connection_failed   blocked_by_firewall Client IP address is not allowed to access the server.  NULL
2013-04-19 16:35:00.0000000 2013-04-19 16:40:00.0000000 [DATABASE]  connection_failed   blocked_by_firewall Client IP address is not allowed to access the server.  NULL
2013-04-19 16:35:00.0000000 2013-04-19 16:40:00.0000000             connection_failed   blocked_by_firewall Client IP address is not allowed to access the server.  NULL
2013-04-19 16:30:00.0000000 2013-04-19 16:35:00.0000000 [DATABASE]  connection_failed   blocked_by_firewall Client IP address is not allowed to access the server.  NULL
2013-04-19 16:30:00.0000000 2013-04-19 16:35:00.0000000             connection_failed   blocked_by_firewall Client IP address is not allowed to access the server.  NULL
2013-04-19 16:25:00.0000000 2013-04-19 16:30:00.0000000 [DATABASE]  connection_failed   blocked_by_firewall Client IP address is not allowed to access the server.  NULL
2013-04-19 16:25:00.0000000 2013-04-19 16:30:00.0000000             connection_failed   blocked_by_firewall Client IP address is not allowed to access the server.  NULL
2013-04-19 16:20:00.0000000 2013-04-19 16:25:00.0000000 [DATABASE]  connection_failed   blocked_by_firewall Client IP address is not allowed to access the server.  NULL
2013-04-19 16:20:00.0000000 2013-04-19 16:25:00.0000000             connection_failed   blocked_by_firewall Client IP address is not allowed to access the server.  NULL
2013-04-19 16:15:00.0000000 2013-04-19 16:20:00.0000000 [DATABASE]  connection_failed   blocked_by_firewall Client IP address is not allowed to access the server.  NULL
```

And an example of our connection string, as requested:

```
  <add name="[MyContext]"
     providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"
     connectionString="
      Server=tcp:[machine].database.windows.net,1433;
          Database=[database];
          User ID=[user]@[machine];
          Password=[password];
          Trusted_Connection=False;
          Encrypt=True;
          Connection Timeout=30;"/>
```

Comment: have you checked out [this documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsazure/ee336245.aspx), and the [TN Retry Logic for Transient Errors is Windows Azure SQL Database](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/4235.retry-logic-for-transient-failures-in-windows-azure-sql-database.aspx)

Comment: I just came across that same article recently.  Check out the updated question, I added the results of a query on the event log, and they all appear to be "blocked_by_firewall" errors, even though none of our users are reporting problems...

Comment: Where are the applications that connect to SQL Azure running from? Are you sure you've provided access for all the IP addresses that need it? Do any of the applications connect from a range of IPs or have dynamically assigned IPs? Can you post the format of your connection strings?

Comment: The DB is accessed by 1 hosted web application and 1 internal application accessed via hosted citrix.  For the web hosting, we added the entire 1-255 range of their IP address, and for the internal app just the single IP address.  So far there have been no reports of problems on either side.  Connection string added to the question.

Comment: We are experiencing the same issue, but we do not have any outside access from any system, it is all Azure hosted.  We have 500+ of these firewall blocks per day.  Azure services are allowed access, but lately we have been having to add IP's of the Azure hosted machines because we have seen a few instances where they are getting blocked even with the allowed setting checked.  Even when these errors are not being thrown, we still see the problem pop up.  This seems like a larger issue.

Comment: I thought the 0.0.0.0 rule took care of all inter-Azure access?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So ever since the first day of launch, we have not seen anymore failed connections.  My current thinking is that there may be a back end process on the Azure side that was not functioning properly with the new instance, but has since either stopped, or been fixed, as we have not changed anything.  I'll let it sit a few more days and if we don't see any more problems, chalk it up to environment setup glitches.

[image]

Here's the status a week or so later.  Not a heavily used site, but no sign of anymore connection errors.

[image]

Comment: I had the same problem on an Azure Website with Mongo, Memcached and Redis. (All 3 self-hosted) Removed dependency to Redis, change Memcached to Azure Cache and Mongo hosting to MongoLabs. The problem stopped appearing. Today I've set up a staging env with a similar configuration and the problems are there again.

Answer (score 1):

I had this same problem and it perplexed me until I realised that I had a SQL Server Management Studio instance open and connected on my home office machine, and my ISP had changed my IP address on me!  As soon as I closed SSMS the failed connections stopped.  Thanks OP for the link to the SQL query, that was useful to know as well!